# React Native - Show Error on the tip of the TextInput

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to show an error if the user enters a blank value in the `TextInput`. But I am not getting the way how could I do this. This is how I want to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to add

```
onChangeText={(txt)=>{ this.filter(txt)
```

on your text input then need to maintain state.

```js
filter(text){
  console.log(text);
  this.setState(data:text)
  if (text === '') {
    //Show your error
  }
  else {
    //Show Success case 
  }
}
```

Comment: Here, I want to know that how can I create this error popup box in react